# .val() and .text() don't work?

Tags: javascript

I want to email div contents via php and form tag.  I have 2 divs with these classes:

```
.simpleCart_items
.simpleCart_total
```

I want to fetch contents from these divs and insert their contents in inputs or textareas, then submit the form to my php file.

I wrote this JQuery code:

```
$('#shopform').submit(function(){
  var items = $('.simpleCart_items').text();
  var tprice = $('.simpleCart_total').text();
  $('#itemsinfo').val(items);
  $('#totalprice').val(tprice);
});
```

and these are my inputs:

```
<textarea id="itemsinfo" style="width:320px; height:160px"></textarea>

<input type="text" id="totalprice"/>
```

but it doesn't work.  The contents didn't move to the input tags.

Comment: I started to fix this.  You should finish.  Please use standard English spelling.  "I" when referring to yourself.  Capital Letters at the start of a sentence.  Sticking to standards makes it easier for people to read and answer your question.

Comment: Did you put your jQuery code into a `$(document).ready(function(){})` (or `$(function(){})`) block?

Comment: @S.Lott: Not everyone on this site is from the USA or speaks/writes English perfectly.  He may not know the correct English standards.

Comment: @Rocket.  I only had two specific requests that most English-as-non-primary-language folks seem to know.  The problem is not "writes English perfectly".  The problem is chat and text messaging where poor spelling is tolerated.  These questions last a long, long time.  Spelling and syntax matter.   This is not chat.  Many errors are accepted, and sometimes even fixed by the kindness of strangers.  But two rules doesn't seem an onerous burden.  Does it?

Comment: @S.Lott: Yeah, I guess you're right.

Comment: sorry for my poor english spelling, i`m persian

Comment: @Rocket yeah you`r right , i must put my codes between $(document).ready(function(){})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be something else in your HTML or script that you are showing us because when I set up a simple test using your code, it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7q6DP/.

This works perfectly fine for me (in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE):

**HTML:**

```
<button id="submitForm">Submit</button>
<div class="simpleCart_items">simpleCart items text</div>
<div class="simpleCart_total">simpleCart total</div>

<textarea id="itemsinfo" style="width:320px height:160px"></textarea><br>
<input type="text" id="totalprice"/>
```

**Javascript** (after page is loaded):

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(){
  var items = $('.simpleCart_items').text();
  var tprice = $('.simpleCart_total').text();
  $('#itemsinfo').val(items);
  $('#totalprice').val(tprice);
});
```

Please show the rest of your code and HTML.

The things to check are:

1. Are there any javascript errors showing in the error console or in the debugger console?
2. Are you initializing your event handlers after the page has loaded?
3. Do any javascript errors show in the debug console when you press the submit button?
4. Is your submitForm event handler getting called?  If you set a breakpoint or put an alert in their, does it get hit?
5. Can you set a breakpoint in your submit handler and see what's happening with the values of items or tprice?
6. Make sure your class names don't have the leading period on them when you put them in your HTML.  It should be `class="simpleCart_items"`, not `class=".simpleCart_items"`.

Comment: Agreed. The code functions properly for me as well, so there must be something somewhere else that is causing it to break.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine when I put it in a page:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/krYQh/

When you click the submit button, the fields are populated with the data. (I added a `return false` in the submit event handler just to keep the form from posting.)

Some possible errors in your code:

- You have used `class=".simpleCart_items"` instead of `class="simpleCart_items"`.
- The form doesn't have `id="shopform"`.
- You have use the ids `shopform`, `itemsinfo` or `totalprice` on any other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use ".html()" instead of ".text" something like below.

```
  $('#shopform').submit(function(){   
  var items = $('.simpleCart_items').html();   
  var tprice = $('.simpleCart_total').html();   

    $('#itemsinfo').html(items);   
    $('#totalprice').val(tprice); 
  });
```

Comment: Using .html() is not needed and isn't his issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should use .innerHTML instead of .text()

Comment: `.value` is a property of `HTMLInputElement`s, not jQuery objects. *edit:* Same holds for `.innerHTML`, it's a property of DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the .val() to get the value for the text areas instead of using .text().

Try using alert(items); before you set the div's contents just to make sure you are actually getting data.

Comment: Other way around.  He wants to set the input's and textarea's content to the div's content.