# Make space or special character between fetched contents

Tags: javascript, textarea, string-formatting

Thanks for helping to solve a problem at:
[.val() and .text() don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435990/val-and-text-dont-work)

Now I have a new question, look at my problem in: http://jsfiddle.net/arlopa/B5aTC/

When you click on "submit", this appears in the textarea:

```
**content 1acontent 2a**
```

If I email this text, the user can't read it!

I want to fix it so that it's formatted like:

```
(content 1a) ( content 2a )
```

OR

```
content 1a

content 2a
```

OR

```
content 1a | content 2a
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JQuery selector is causing the formatting issue. What you can do is get a collection of the elements and then iterate over them using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to build up the way you want to display them.

Here is your javascript with the items updated to display with a pipe, and with your original total code:

```
$('#shopform').submit(function() {
    var items = '';
    var tprice = $('.simpleCart_total').text();

$.each($('.simpleCart_items'), function(index, value) { 
    items = index === 0 ? value.textContent : items + ' | ' + value.textContent;
});

    $('#itemsinfo').val(items);
    $('#totalprice').val(tprice);
    return false;
});
```